# execute simple stored procedure with python sql connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have a very simple stored procedure on a  mysql database, taking 4 VARCHAR parameters and performing an insert operation into some table (the reason I have this is to be able to better control the permissions I give to my applications). When I call the procedure directly from mysql as follows:

```
CALL my_proc('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd');
```

the procedure does its job and the record gets inserted in the relevant table. Now when I try that via python (using mysql.connector), somehow  the code seems to execute fine (no errors), but it didn't perform the expected insert statement. My code is something like this:

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error, Warning
from helpers import get_config


def connect():
    # helper procedure to fetch credentials from config.ini
    db_config = get_config('mysql')

    try:
        print('Connecting...')
        conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)

        if conn.is_connected():
            print('connected')
            return conn
        else:
            print('could not connect')
            return None

    except Error as e:
        print(e)


def insert_record(conn, a, b, c, d):
    try:
        args = [a, b, c, d]
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print('inserting {0} into database ''{1}'''.format(args, conn.database))
        statement = "CALL my_proc('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}');".format(args)
        print(statement)
        cursor.execute(statement)
        #cursor.callproc('my_proc', args)

    except (Error, Warning) as e:
        print e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = connect()
    insert_listen_record(conn, 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd')
    disconnect(conn)
```

The output is quite what you would expect:

```
connecting...
connected
inserting ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'] into the database
CALL my_proc('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd');
connection closed
```

As you can see in the commented-out code in the procedure insert_record, I also tried to use cursor.callproc instead of cursor.execute, but with the same (lack of) result. Not sure what I am doing wrong, and as I am new to all of this, I don't even know where to start debugging: the stored procedure works fine, there are no error messages and stepping through the code in debug mode everything seems fine...

Comment: You might want to add a `COMMIT` statement at the end of your `statement` string. I don't know much MySQL, but in MSSQL,I always have to send a `COMMIT` after making/deleting a table etc. for it to actually persist in the database.

Comment: simple as that eh... added conn.commit() and it did the trick indeed. Thx @MathewSavage !